# How to extract city and state code from an address

Tags: swift

I have a string var looks like this:

```
str = "1234 South St, Boston, MA"
```

Is there any way that I can extract only the city and state code?
So I want this result:

```
extractedStr = "Boston, MA"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `NSDataDetector` for `CheckingType.address` and get city and state `NSTextCheckingKey`s from its `addressComponents`:

```
let str = "1234 South St, Boston, MA"
do {
    if let addressComponents = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.address.rawValue)
        .matches(in: str, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: str.utf16.count)).first?.addressComponents,
        let city = addressComponents[.city],
        let state = addressComponents[.state] {

        print("city:", city)
        print("state:", state)

        let result = "\(city), \(state)"
        print(result)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

This will print

> city: Boston
>
> state: MA
>
> Boston, MA

Comment: Thank you for your help! I can have done what I wanted to do!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the structure of the string: (swift 4.0 +)

```
var str = "1234 South St, Boston, MA"
let splitted = str.components(separatedBy: ",")
splitted.map{ $0.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "") }
var city = splitted[1]
var state = splitted[2]

print("City:\(city), State:\(state)")
```